# VS Code tries to run c++ and gnu++ at the same time

Tags: macos, c++17, clang++

Whenever I try to run any code in VS code one Mac m2 i get an error with the issue being it trying to run Gnu++ and C++ 17 at the same time. The error in terminal is:

```
 *  Executing task: C/C++: clang build active file 

Starting build...
/usr/bin/clang -std=gnu++14 -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -g /Users/jst_/Coding/VS.Code_C++/Main.CPP -o /Users/jst_/Coding/VS.Code_C++/Main
ld: Undefined symbols:
 
tons of random crap I dont understand 50 lines long

 referenced from:
      /private/var/folders/g9/b9nx0j1x5cs123fg6skrl0600000gn/T/Main-c82fef.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

the code was

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

I tried looking for gnu++ in the properties and tasks (.json) and nothing. I never installed it. The only extensions in vscode I have is the one for C++ and in terminal is brew and clang.

Comment: That you have both `-std=gnu++14` and  `-std=c++17` in there is harmless. The compiler will ignore the first one and use the latter option. What is not correct however is that you call `clang` instead of `clang++`. You need `clang++` for compiling C++. Fix that in your configuration files.

Comment: `tons of random crap I dont understand 50 lines long` Don't cut off what you don't understand. It's not a reason to deprive SO users of possible useful information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clang not working. Undefined symbol error. Code compiles fine in gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151630/clang-not-working-undefined-symbol-error-code-compiles-fine-in-gcc)